# Can't loop through an array of objects in Typescript (Angular)

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angular-components

in my project I'm fetching data from an API (trip entities). This is my model:

```
  //Trip.model.ts
  export class Trip{
  created_at?:Date;
  updated_at?:Date;
 .... bunch of fields
}
```

In my component I'm fetching the data and assigning it to the **trips** variable. However, when I'm trying to access any of the items in the **trips** array I get 'undefined'. I also can't loop through it, I tried both **forEach** and **for...in/of**. 
I tried using an interface instead of a class but with no luck. How can I loop through that array of objects in order to use the data in it? 
Component's code:

```
  userName:string='';
  trips:Trip[]=[];
  moment:any=moment;
  usersData:any={};

  constructor(private auth: AuthService,
              private storage: LocalStorageService,
              private translate: TranslateService,
              private tripService: TripService){}

    ngOnInit(): void {
    console.log(this.translate.currentLang)
    this.userName=localStorage.getItem('username')!;
    this.fetchTrips();
    this.fetchPics();
  }

  fetchTrips() {
    this.tripService.getTrips().subscribe({
      next: data => {
        data[0].data.forEach((value) => {
          let trip: Trip = plainToInstance(Trip,value);
          this.trips.push(trip);
        });
      }, error: error => {
        console.log(error);
      }
    });
  }
  //fetchPics because I want to extract 
  //user's profile pics' urls from the trips array
  fetchPics(){
    console.log(this.trips);
    console.log(this.trips[0]);
    this.trips.forEach((trip)=>{
      console.log(trip);
    });
  }
```

getTrips service method:

```
getTrips(){
    return this.http.get<any>(Api.API+Endpoints.TRIP);
  }
```

This is what shows when I

```
console.log(this.trips)
```

after assignment.

[image]

Data from the API:

[image]

Pictures cropped to make them more readable.

Comment: Your Trip model shows an object, not an array?

Comment: Can you show an example of what getTrips sub returns? Also, there are some other problems in your code, but let's leave it for the next step.

Comment: @MikeOne just edited what it shows, it's an array right?

Comment: @MishaMashina just added, is that what you meant?

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to get access to this.trips value before you actually have your data on it.This happens becouse you get that data asynchronously, just inside the subscribe of this.tripService.getTrips()

So, in order to solve your problem, you just need to move this invoke:

```
 this.fetchPics();
```

inside the subscribe of fetchTrips() method, like this:

```
fetchTrips() {
    this.tripService.getTrips().subscribe({
      next: data => {
        data[0].data.forEach((value) => {
          let trip: Trip = plainToInstance(Trip,value);
          this.trips.push(trip);

          this.fetchPics();

        });
      }, error: error => {
        console.log(error);
      }
    });
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

The function `fetchPics()` executes before your `getTrips` call ends. You need to call the method only after your HTTP call ends, and after you populate your `trips` array successfully.

```js
fetchTrips() {
    this.tripService.getTrips().subscribe({
      next: data => {
        //Populate your trips array
        data[0].data.forEach((value) => {
          let trip: Trip = plainToInstance(Trip,value);
          this.trips.push(trip);
        });
        // this is where you need to call
        this.fetchPics(); 
      }, error: error => {
        console.log(error);
      }
    });
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

This is happening because of JS is asynchronous. you are making an http request here, that may take some time to get data from server. let's assume that might take 1 minute untill then compiler will not stop it's execution process In that 1 min of time it will execute next statements.because of that **your fetchpics() method is being executed before fecthtrips() execution done**. To overcome this we can use async, await as like below.

```
async fetchTrips() {
    this.tripService.getTrips().subscribe({
      next: data => await {
        data[0].data.forEach((value) => {
          let trip: Trip = plainToInstance(Trip,value);
          this.trips.push(trip);
        });
  }, error: error => {
    console.log(error);
  }
});
```

}